# Error 2003: Undeclared "Form1"

Tags: delphi

Работаю, работаю, и вдруг вылетает какое-то сообщение типа (Delphi 2010)

> "Tform1.Form тутуту ... removed?"

или

> "Form1.Tform тутуту ... removed?"

... не успев подумать, пальцы уже нажали "ДА". И потом перестало компилироваться.

> Error 2003: Undeclared "Form1"

И с других модулей Form1 недоступно... Как будто его нет вообще. Понимаю, что я как-то нечаянно удалил объявление формы, но и не знаю как восстановить, чтоб был доступен всем остальным модулям... Где это хранится? Форма и элементы на нем, я вижу (в unit1)... В модулях не доступен (unit1,unit2, unit3, unit4, etc).

Ура!!!! Вспомнил че за ошибка ..
Вот оно:`"Field Form1.Form1 does not a corresponding component.Remove the declaration???"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В самом верху где объявлены процедуры удали их + удали всё где они использовались.

Ну или погляди вверху

```
 uses  StdCtrls
```

Comment: Процедуры, только относящие к form1 (public,private)
???Или еще и ручн. объявленные???